# ifconfig -a in a shell script

Tags: shell-script, variable, output

I am writing a shell script to start my network in my virtual machine on boot, since it does not do this right away for some reason with a snapshot of a virtual machine.

Since the `eth` device starts as being down, I have to get that device name with the following script and then start the device as well:

```
gateway=ifconfig -a | awk '/eth/ {print $1}'
dhclient $gateway
```

However I keep getting the following error, `line 1: -a: command not found`. `ifconfig -a` works however from the command line.

Is there a way to get `ifconfig -a` to work in my shell script?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must use [command substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst), otherwise, `bash` will think you assigned `ifconfig` result to variable `gateway` then run command `-a`:

```
gateway=$(ifconfig -a | awk '/eth/ {print $1}')
dhclient $gateway
```

Comment: thank you that works, I knew it had to do with how it was interpreting the script but couldn't pinpoint it.

Comment: The right single quote is wrongly placed. For some reason, stack exchange is too stupid to accept a minor edit.